# Javascript Stuck in Cache

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have a HTML document which I am developing a `.js` file for. My problem is, my browser is still using an outdated version of the `.js` script, which it stored in the cache when it was used. Any modifications to the actual `.js` script make no difference. Clearing the cache didn't help... How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry guys. Turns out the problem was something totally unrelated... I had some overlapping functions from an old (unneeded) `.js` script, which were taking priority over the one I'm editing.

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you try with filename.js?v=2, and after another changes filename.js?v=3?
2. Another possibillity is, that you attached wrong file, not this what you're editing.
3. Restart the browser? But I dont suspect, its this issue.
4. If the file is on remote server, try uploading again, and then download the file and check for the changes. It may be caching mechanism on the server too, so try to restart apache if you've got permissions.

Can you add more code?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file on the server. Load the page. Ensure that it didn't find the script. Rename the script back to its original name. Test to see of it loads properly.

If this fails, it may be time to reboot your web server.